# pymongo + discord message timer not working well together

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo, discord.py

I am currently trying to make a message timer for discord, basically what I want is when a user sets a message timer I want the message to be sent every x seconds, but for some reason it is only sending the message in one channel even though I have already set it up in two channels.

Here is my code.

```
async def on_ready(self):
    print("SmartCord rewrite is ready!")
    self.remove_command('help')
    #ch = self.get_channel(446904504210948099)
    #await ch.send("\n".join(good))
    await self.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name=f"{len(self.guilds)} Guilds | /help", url="https://www.twitch.tv/smartcord"))
    for channel in self.get_all_channels():
        if db.messagetimers.find({"channel_id":str(channel.id)}).count():
            for x in db.messagetimers.find({"channel_id":str(channel.id)}):
                message = x['message']
                chan = x['channel_id']
            y = self.get_channel(int(chan))
            while True:
                await y.send(message)
                await asyncio.sleep(60) # Using 60 seconds as an example
```

Since I'm not really that good with python I don't really know what to do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an indentation error to me. You are setting the `chan` variable in a loop, then use it outside that loop to resolve the channel into the `y` variable. So without looking too deep into the code, I'd assume that the last four lines need one more level of indentation.

Comment: sadly it doesn't fix the issue, I tried making a command where they would be able to make a custom command and store the command and the response in the database and what I found out that it was only getting the last data from the database.